# How could I set the default time for the datetimepicker that should be save on the database

Tags: python, django, datetimepicker

How could I set the default time for this datetimepicker, right now when i save it to the database it shows the YYYY-MM-DD-00:00:00 format. I wanted to set to YYYY-MM-DD-00:59:59 for the holiday_end_date and YYYY-MM-DD-00:00:00 for the start date.

I wa

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".dtpicker").datetimepicker({
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
    useCurrent: false,
    icons:
        {
            next: 'fa fa-angle-right',
            previous: 'fa fa-angle-left'
        }
})

$(document).on("click", "#add_holiday_btn", function () {
            if ($('#holiday_end_date', '#holiday_start_date').val() == ''){
            return
        }
 }); })
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this option to datetimepicker function

```
defaultDate: "2019-12-20"
```

then it will be

```
$(".dtpicker").datetimepicker({
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
    useCurrent: false,
    defaultDate: "2019-12-20",
    icons:
        {
            next: 'fa fa-angle-right',
            previous: 'fa fa-angle-left'
        }
})
```

Comment: I was working with TIME, but would that effect both start_date and end_date?